# Jira GitLab Integration

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration

I just like to ask a question, my current situation is that we have a product team (building the physical device ) that is using Jira, and a software team that is using GitLab, and for most of the time, the product team is writing task requirements in Jira, and the software team will write the task requirements in GitLab. from a product owner's point of view, the same requirement often has to be duplicated to both places (Jira and GitLab).

Is there a way to Integrate Jira with GitLab so the same information can be written in one place but nicely duplicated to the other? (I have tried the integration options offered by GitLab to show issues and merge requests on Jira, it is nice but it is not what I am after)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an integration for Jira that you can set up in your Gitlab project's Integrations settings. To be able to do exactly what you're looking for, you need to be a paid Gitlab user, but you can still get some useful functionality if you're a free user.
Free features include linking a Jira issue with gitlab by mentioning it in a commit message or merge request, resolve a Jira issue from a commit or merge request, display a pipeline's details in a links Jira issue, etc.

As a paid user you can view and work on all Jira issues directly in Gitlab.

The Jira integration documentation and full features are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could check also Gitlab.com official plugin for Jira